# How do I turn this into sorted Order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I do this in sorted Order?

This assignment here: https://jsfiddle.net/debhxnqc/27/

The code is here:

```
Guess:

<input type="textbox" id="index" value="12">
<br/> Get Number:

<button id="click" onclick="InsertGuess(1000,0,'',0)">Generate</button>
<div id="guess"></div>

<script>

var InsertGuess = function(max, min, finalStr, count) {
  var str = 'Guessed :';
  var guessnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

  if (document.getElementById('index').value > guessnum) {
    finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum, ' too low <br>');
    count = count + 1;
    return InsertGuess(max, guessnum, finalStr, count);
  } else if (document.getElementById('index').value < guessnum) {
    finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum, ' too high <br>');
    count = count + 1;
    return InsertGuess(guessnum, min, finalStr, count);
  } else {
    count = count + 1;
    finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum, ' Got it !!!<br>');
    finalStr = finalStr.concat('It took me ' + count + ' tries ');
    document.getElementById('guess').innerHTML = finalStr;
    return;
  }
}


</script>
```

I was informed that this needs to be done in sorted order when pressing the 'generate button'.

```
**Example**: When pressing generate the result would show:

532 too high
47 too high
14 too high
8 too low
10 too low
11 too low
12 Got it !!!
It took me 7 tries
```

Instead I was told it needs to show as:

```
532 too high
147 too high
214 too high
98 too low
76 too low
45 too low
12 Got it !!!
It took me 7 tries
```

In sorted order. How would I do that?

Comment: rewrite it using array(s) if you have to sort it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var InsertGuess = function(max,min,finalStr,count) {
  var sortedArray = [];
  var guess = function (max,min,finalStr,count) {
    var guessnum = Math.floor(Math.random() *(max-min+1)+min);
    if(document.getElementById('index').value > guessnum){
      sortedArray.push([guessnum , ' too low <br>']);
      count=count+1;
      return guess(max,guessnum,finalStr,count);
    }else if(document.getElementById('index').value < guessnum) {
      sortedArray.push([guessnum, ' too high <br>']);
      count=count+1;
      return guess(guessnum,min,finalStr,count);
    }else{
      count=count+1;    
      sortedArray.sort(function (a,b) {return b[0] - a[0]});
      finalStr = finalStr.concat(sortedArray.join(''));
      finalStr = finalStr.concat(guessnum , ' Got it !!!<br>');
      finalStr = finalStr.concat('It took me '+ count +' tries ');
      document.getElementById('guess').innerHTML= finalStr;
      return ;
    }
  }
  guess(max,min,finalStr,count);
}
```

```html
Guess:
<input type="textbox" id="index" value="12">
<br/> Get Number:

<button id="click" onclick="InsertGuess(1000,0,'',0)">Generate</button>
<div id="guess"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works magnificently; I understand how you did it now.

Comment: I just sorted the data at the end of the algorithm, but there's a way to make it actually incremental.  I've made a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/puxopo/1/edit?js,output), notice that I'm still sorting at the end there because when the guess is lower we have to go up anyway.